# PHP explode with included txt file

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

PHP
When using a txt included file the explode fails. The txt file is just this: `a,b,c,d,e`
When not an include the string 'explodes' into an array.

```
$data = include("data.txt");
settype($data,"string");

print "<br><br>type: ".gettype($data)."<br>";

$data = explode(",",$data);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: You'll want to use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), not [`include`](http://php.net/include).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include()` and `require()` are meant to be used with PHP scripts.

For importing raw data, consider [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), which will return a string.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
$data = file_get_contents("data.txt");**


print "<br><br>type: ".gettype($data)."<br>";

$data = explode(",",$data);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Sidenote: The whole settype/gettype in this case is useless. `file_get_contents()` *always* returns the file as string

Comment: you don't need to answer any simple question you find. Especially if it has already an answer which tells the same as you. Just upvote that on go on in such cases